# How to adapt my plugin to Multisite?

Tags: php, wordpress, multisite

I have many plugins that I wrote for WordPress, and now I want to adapt them to MU.
What are the *considerations / best practices / workflow / functions / pitfalls* that I have to *follow / avoid / adapt* in order to 'upgrade' my plugins to support also Multisite installations?

For example, but not limited to:

- Enqueue scripts/register
- Incuding files (php, images)
- Paths for custom files uploads
- `$wpdb`
- Activation, uninstall, deactivation
- Handling of admin specific pages

In the Codex, there are *sometimes* remarks about Multisite in single function description, but I did not find any one-stop page that address this subject.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

As for enqueuing and including, things go as normal. Plugin path and URL are the same.

I never dealt with anything related to upload paths in Multisite and I guess normally WP takes care of this.

---

## `$wpdb`

There is a commonly used snippet to iterate through all blogs:

```
global $wpdb;
$blogs = $wpdb->get_results("
    SELECT blog_id
    FROM {$wpdb->blogs}
    WHERE site_id = '{$wpdb->siteid}'
    AND spam = '0'
    AND deleted = '0'
    AND archived = '0'
");
$original_blog_id = get_current_blog_id();   
foreach ( $blogs as $blog_id ) 
{
    switch_to_blog( $blog_id->blog_id );
    // do something in the blog, like:
    // update_option()
}   
switch_to_blog( $original_blog_id );
```

You may find examples where `restore_current_blog()` is used instead of `switch_to_blog( $original_blog_id )`. But here's why `switch` is more reliable: [restore_current_blog() vs switch_to_blog()](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/89113/12615).

---

## `$blog_id`

Execute some function or hook according to the blog ID:

```
global $blog_id;
if( $blog_id != 3 )
    add_image_size( 'category-thumb', 300, 9999 ); //300 pixels wide (and unlimited height)
```

Or maybe:

```
if( 
    'child.multisite.com' === $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] 
    || 
    'domain-mapped-child.com' === $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']
    )
{
    // do_something();
}
```

---

## Install - Network Activation only

Using the plugin header `Network: true` <sup>(see: **Sample Plugin**)</sup> will only display the plugin in the page `/wp-admin/network/plugins.php`. With this header in place, we can use the following to block certain actions meant to happen if the plugin is Network only.

```
function my_plugin_block_something()
{
    $plugin = plugin_basename( __FILE__ );
    if( !is_network_only_plugin( $plugin ) )
        wp_die(
            'Sorry, this action is meant for Network only', 
            'Network only',  
            array( 
                'response' => 500, 
                'back_link' => true 
            )
        );    
}
```

---

## Uninstall

For (De)Activation, it depends on each plugin. But, for Uninstalling, this is the code I use in the file [`uninstall.php`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_uninstall_hook):

```
<?php
/**
 * Uninstall plugin - Single and Multisite
 * Source: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/80350/12615
 */

// Make sure that we are uninstalling
if ( !defined( 'WP_UNINSTALL_PLUGIN' ) ) 
    exit();

// Leave no trail
$option_name = 'HardCodedOptionName';

if ( !is_multisite() ) 
{
    delete_option( $option_name );
} 
else 
{
    global $wpdb;
    $blog_ids = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT blog_id FROM $wpdb->blogs" );
    $original_blog_id = get_current_blog_id();

    foreach ( $blog_ids as $blog_id ) 
    {
        switch_to_blog( $blog_id );
        delete_option( $option_name );    
    }
    switch_to_blog( $original_blog_id );
}
```

---

## Admin Pages

#### 1) Adding an admin page

To add an administration menu we check if `is_multisite()` and modify the hook accordingly:

```
$hook = is_multisite() ? 'network_' : '';
add_action( "{$hook}admin_menu", 'unique_prefix_function_callback' );
```

#### 2) Check for Multisite dashboard and modify the admin URL:

```
// Check for MS dashboard
if( is_network_admin() )
    $url = network_admin_url( 'plugins.php' );
else
    $url = admin_url( 'plugins.php' );
```

#### 3) Workaround to show interface elements only in main site

Without creating a Network Admin Menu (action hook `network_admin_menu`), it is possible to show some part of the plugin **only in the main site**.

I started to include some Multisite functionality in my [biggest plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/many-tips-together/) and did the following to restrict one part of the plugin options to the main site. Meaning, if the plugin is activated in a sub site, the option **won't show up**.

```
$this->multisite = is_multisite() 
        ? ( is_super_admin() && is_main_site() ) // must meet this 2 conditions to be "our multisite"
        : false;
```

<sup>Looking at this again, maybe it can be simply: `is_multisite() && is_super_admin() && is_main_site()`. Note that the last two return `true` in single sites.</sup>

And then:

```
if( $this->multisite )
    echo "Something only for the main site, i.e.: Super Admin!";
```

#### 4) Collection of useful hooks and functions.

**Hooks**: [`network_admin_menu`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=network_admin_menu), [`wpmu_new_blog`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/70977/12615), [`signup_blogform`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=signup_blogform), [`wpmu_blogs_columns`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=wpmu_blogs_columns), [`manage_sites_custom_column`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=manage_sites_custom_column), `manage_blogs_custom_column`, [`wp_dashboard_setup`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/67876/12615), [`network_admin_notices`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/76145/12615), [`site_option_active_sitewide_plugins`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/3426/12615), `{$hook}admin_menu`

**Functions**: [`is_multisite`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=is_multisite%20is:answer), [`is_super_admin`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=is_super_admin%20is:answer) [`is_main_site`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=is_main_site), [`get_blogs_of_user`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/91745/12615), [`update_blog_option`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=update_blog_option), `is_network_admin`, `network_admin_url`, `is_network_only_plugin`

<sup>*PS: I rather link to WordPress Answers than to the Codex, as there'll be more examples of working code.*</sup>

---

## Sample plugin

I've just rolled a Multisite plugin, [Network Deactivated but Active Elsewhere](https://github.com/brasofilo/Network-Deactivated-but-Active-Elsewhere), and made a **non-working** resumed annotated version bellow (see GitHub for the finished full working version). The finished plugin is purely functional, there's no settings interface.

<sup>Note that the plugin header has `Network: true`. It prevents the plugin from [showing in child sites](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/74649/12615).</sup>

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Network Deactivated but Active Elsewhere
 * Network: true
 */ 

/**
 * Start the plugin only if in Admin side and if site is Multisite
 */
if( is_admin() && is_multisite() )
{
    add_action(
        'plugins_loaded',
        array ( B5F_Blog_Active_Plugins_Multisite::get_instance(), 'plugin_setup' )
    );
}    

/**
 * Based on Plugin Class Demo - https://gist.github.com/toscho/3804204 
 */
class B5F_Blog_Active_Plugins_Multisite
{
    protected static $instance = NULL;
    public $blogs = array();
    public $plugin_url = '';
    public $plugin_path = '';

    public static function get_instance()
    {
        NULL === self::$instance and self::$instance = new self;
        return self::$instance;
    }

    /**
     * Plugin URL and Path work as normal
     */
    public function plugin_setup()
    {
        $this->plugin_url    = plugins_url( '/', __FILE__ );
        $this->plugin_path   = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ );
        add_action( 
            'load-plugins.php', 
            array( $this, 'load_blogs' ) 
        );
    }

    public function __construct() {}

    public function load_blogs()
    { 
        /**
         * Using "is_network" property from $current_screen global variable.
         * Run only in /wp-admin/network/plugins.php
         */
        global $current_screen;
        if( !$current_screen->is_network )
            return;

        /**
         * A couple of Multisite-only filter hooks and a regular one.
         */
        add_action( 
                'network_admin_plugin_action_links', 
                array( $this, 'list_plugins' ), 
                10, 4 
        );
        add_filter( 
                'views_plugins-network', // 'views_{$current_screen->id}'
                array( $this, 'inactive_views' ), 
                10, 1 
        );
        add_action(
                'admin_print_scripts',
                array( $this, 'enqueue')
        );

        /**
         * This query is quite frequent to retrieve all blog IDs.
         */
        global $wpdb;
        $this->blogs = $wpdb->get_results(
                " SELECT blog_id, domain 
                FROM {$wpdb->blogs}
                WHERE site_id = '{$wpdb->siteid}'
                AND spam = '0'
                AND deleted = '0'
                AND archived = '0' "
        );  
    }

    /**
     * Enqueue script and style normally.
     */
    public function enqueue()
    {
        wp_enqueue_script( 
                'ndbae-js', 
                $this->plugin_url . '/ndbae.js', 
                array(), 
                false, 
                true 
        );
        wp_enqueue_style( 
                'ndbae-css', 
                $this->plugin_url . '/ndbae.css'
        );
    }

    /**
     * Check if plugin is active in any blog
     * Using Multisite function get_blog_option
     */
    private function get_network_plugins_active( $plug )
    {
        $active_in_blogs = array();
        foreach( $this->blogs as $blog )
        {
            $the_plugs = get_blog_option( $blog['blog_id'], 'active_plugins' );
            foreach( $the_plugs as $value )
            {
                if( $value == $plug )
                    $active_in_blogs[] = $blog['domain'];
            }
        }
        return $active_in_blogs;
    }
}
```

---

## Other resources - e-books

Not directly related to plugin development, but kind of essential to Multisite management.
The e-books are written by no less than two giants of Multisite: Mika Epstein (aka Ipstenu) and Andrea Rennick.

- [**WordPress Multisite 101**](http://halfelf.org/ebooks/wordpress-multisite-101/)
- [**WordPress Multisite 110**](http://halfelf.org/ebooks/wordpress-multisite-110/)

Comment: Some Great Great Info here ..I would give you not +1 but +100 if i could.. Thanks . all useful. as wp-mu is a bit of a "bastard" child, no one really knows how to deal with it well (just see the netword options admin UI) . Anyhow, one question , about the `Network: true` in the docblock , is it possible to somehow trigger it also for third-party plugins ? (where it is not in the original docblock ? )

Comment: god.. too many info to process :-) . and also I somehow never noticed that featrue . anyhow, thanks again. and if you come up with more stuff, it would be great if you will add it to this answer ..

Comment: Your first example of iterating through all blogs uses switch_to_blog($original_blog_id) after the loop instead of restore_current_blog() at the end of each iteration. You cite [restore_current_blog() vs switch_to_blog()](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/89113/12615), but the example code does not include
    unset ( $GLOBALS['_wp_switched_stack'] );
    $GLOBALS['switched'] = false;
which are necessary in order to avoid unwanted behavior, according to the cited article.

Comment: Amazing synopsis. Can we get this added to the WordPress codex somewhere?

Comment: @MikeNGarrett, done ;) http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network#Related_Articles

Comment: @brasofilo I don't see anything like this at your link.  This is probably the best synopsis I've been able to find for this anywhere.

Comment: In the snippet to iterate through all blogs, the use of restore_current_blog() is the recommended way to return to the original blog, by WordPress developers, according to: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/switch_to_blog. If you are tempted to use switch_to_blog( $original_blog_id ), because it is faster (and not more reliable, as stated), you MUST clear afterward the global variables which monitors the switching, as warned by WordPress developers here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/restore_current_blog#Notes.