# Build global plugin for Wordpress multisite - admin notes

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I would like to build a simple plugin  for Wordpress - just one textarea field to take notes about the multisite installation.

There's the how-to in Wordpress Codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages, and there are also some plugins that do this, the problem is my "notes" are stored only for the site I'm currently on.

What is the way to build a plugin that would appear on all the subsites of multisite install, with the same content stored?

Thanks

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15940351/1287812).

Comment: You'd just build a regular plugin and activate it "network" wide.