# Super-Editor/Super-Author for WP network of sites?

Tags: wordpress

I'm developing a WP network which will include many sites, all of which will be edited by the same largish group of users. I'd very much prefer to not give super-administrator privileges to all of these users, though, so I'm wondering if it's possible to create a "super-editor" role/user group that would allow users to edit/author all sites within the network, but not be able to actually administer the network, etc.

I've found plugins that allow for cloning blogs and copying users from one blog to another, but it would be great to be able to simply create user once and give them appropriate network wide privs, and similarly delete a user once from the network to revoke privs.

Any clues? My Google-Fu is failing on this one.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Paste this code in your themes function.php file and customize as your need.

```
/* Add member role to the site */
add_role('member', 'Member', array(
    'read' => true,
    'edit_posts' => true,
    'delete_posts' => true,
));

/* Add snypher role to the site */
add_role('snypher', 'Snypher', array(
    'read' => true,
    'edit_posts' => true,
    'delete_posts' => true,
));

/* remove the unnecessary roles */
remove_role('subscriber');
remove_role('editor');
remove_role('author');
remove_role('contributor');
```

Hope this two links helps you more:

[1] http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_role

[2] http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_cap

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you, Krunal and @brasofilo. This helps quite a bit, but doesn't address the part I'm really struggling with, which is granting the these users **network wide** editor access to all sites in the network, rather than having to add them to each site individually. We'll have 100s of sites in this network, so adding and removing users will become a problem quickly. What I'm looking for is a way to create a role that grants editor-level access to all sites in network, similar to how granting super-admin status allows access to all sites. Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom role with many powers, as per Krunai Shah answer. Then create a [Must Use](http://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins) plugin and polish the [following code](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53675/blocking-administrative-access-to-authors-and-subcribers) to your needs:

```
<?
/**
 * Plugin Name: Network Access
 */

/**
  * Redirect Authors and Subscribers to the site front page
  * Except if viewing the Profile page
  */
add_action('admin_init','wpse_53675_block_users');
function wpse_53675_block_users()
{
    global $pagenow;
    if( 'profile.php' == $pagenow ) // use in_array to put a bunch of prohibited pages
        return;

    if( !current_user_can('delete_pages') ) 
    {   
        wp_redirect( get_home_url(), 301 ); 
        exit;
    }
}

/**
 * Hide all menus from the Admin panel
 * Except the profile item
 */
add_action('admin_menu', 'wpse_53675_remove_admin_menus', 999);
function wpse_53675_remove_admin_menus() {
    if( !current_user_can('delete_pages') ) 
    {
        remove_menu_page('index.php');
        remove_menu_page('edit.php');
        remove_menu_page('upload.php');
        remove_menu_page('link-manager.php');
        remove_menu_page('edit.php?post_type=page');
        remove_menu_page('edit-comments.php');
        remove_menu_page('tools.php');
    }
}
```

Useful [Q&A: How to adapt my plugin to Multisite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13960514/how-to-adapt-my-plugin-to-multisite/15940351#15940351).