# WPMU Plugin Availability and Activation - How to Control Both

Tags: wordpress, plugins, wpmu

I'm working on a plugin which when activated on the network it must run on all blogs, not optional to users.

I'm confused - when I network-deactivate the plugin I see instances are still activated on other blogs.

Perhaps I am confused.

How do you:

- Require a plugin so that it cannot be activated or deactivated?
- Mass-activate or mass-deactivate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much probably, that's because they were previously active at the individual sites when you Network Activated. And when you Network Deactivate, they go back to their previous status "activated on single site".

If you want your plugin to used exclusively as a Network plugin, add the following header info:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Your plugin
 * Network: true
 */
```

Post of interest: [How to adapt my plugin to Multisite?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13960514/1287812)

---

> Require a plugin so that it cannot be activated or deactivated?

If understood correctly, you're looking for a [Must Use plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins)

> Mass-activate or mass-deactivate?

There are plugins for that, like [this](http://wordpress.org/plugins/multisite-plugin-manager/) and [this](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wpmu-plugin-manager/).